# Row of images that fit to scale in Flexbox/Grid?

Tags: css

I'm trying to display a row of images using pure CSS, where the result would be that all images have the same height. For example, a taller image would shrink if it was next to a smaller image. There can be 2-6 images in a row. Given a 9:16 image and a 16:9 image, the result would ideally look something like this:

[image]

I initially tried to use Flexbox, but the column widths don't change - the image inside just scales to fit inside. I thought CSS Grid might work instead, but I can't get that working either.

Here's the HTML:

```
<p class="side-by-side-images">
<img src=""> // Tall image
<img src=""> // wide image
</p>
```

The current CSS Grid implementation:

```
.side-by-side-images {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The current result:

[image]

Comment: Will you know the size of the images or will it be dynamic?

Comment: It will be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding from [jons' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56640859/8144506):

You can set your fixed height (the height you want for all of your images, regardless of width) in the image container:

```
.image-container {
  display:flex;
  height:200px;
  background:gray;
}
```

And set the height of all images to that of its container:

```
.image-container img {
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
}
```

Result:
[view on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBXmXz)

Alternatively, including the gaps as shown in your image: [view on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqKRKp)

Answer (score 0):

I would just do

```
img {
  height: 300px; // or whatever value you want
  width: auto;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

If you know the sizes of the images, the math could be more specific.